# JHipster After creating sample entity nothing is shown in the browser

Tags: java, jhipster

I have created a sample application with a very simple entity "stock" with an String id.
All pre-build and unit tests run without errors, but when I open the generated application, I can not see the dialog allowing me to create or see "stocks". Just the header and footer.

The only warning I see is this one:

```
I'm all done. Running bower install & npm install for you to install the required dependencies. If this fails, try running the command yourself.

'bower' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
npm WARN package.json stokker@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.1
```

Could this be related? Do I need to do any additional "bower" installation?
I followed the installation process shown in the JHipster website (Node.js and Yeoman). I´m running on Windows.

**UPDATE**: I have installed bower manually using `npm bower install`and the error is not fixed. Also I have noticed that the upper menu is not working so I think this problem  might be caused by some JavaScript problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being a noob in this field, I missed several installation steps not shown in the [website](https://jhipster.github.io/installation.html):

- Git needs to be set in the PATH environment variable.
- You need to run this command in order to manually install bower:

  `npm install -g bower`

None of these steps are shown in the installation guidelines so I will try to contact the JHipster support in case they modify their website (and save other people´s time).

Comment: You may be a noob in this field, but at least you are using JHipster before it becomes mainstream!