# Jhipster display "this is your footer" only. ReferenceError: angular is not defined

Tags: angularjs, bower, jhipster

I read 
[JHipster After creating sample entity nothing is shown in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27034885/jhipster-after-creating-sample-entity-nothing-is-shown-in-the-browser)
.In my case bower seem fine. It have the angularjs lib
[(When use bower list)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8Up5.png). Why it still can't reference to angularjs? If you have any suggestion on where to investigate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you provide the output from your browser's JavaScript console? Look for a syntax error.

Also you can try

```
grunt wiredep
```

in order to inject your bower dependencies into your source code (normally index.html).

Comment: I used bower install and it done successfully without error. Then I run yo jhipster again. then it notice me should rebuild node-sass. I rebuild node-sass and the web up and running, the error is gone. May be the package node-sass is build fail but somehow bower still think it already build?

Answer (score 0):

Your index.html has no dependencies. You can copy them from sample-app.

Comment: Is it because of node-sass build failed?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it may be problem with system variables (bower and grunt)