# Run project on Jhipster only shows "This is your footer"

Tags: angularjs, spring, jhipster

I have read question [Jhipster display "this is your footer" only. ReferenceError: angular is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34176079/jhipster-display-this-is-your-footer-only-referenceerror-angular-is-not-defi) . Answer on this question do not help me. When I have run jhipster project - window browser showed only text "This is your footer". 
Screen from browser:
[image]

node version: v4.2.6

npm version: 3.5.3

this is a bower.json:

```
    {
    "name": "tanga",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "appPath": "src/main/webapp",
    "testPath": "src/test/javascript/spec",
    "dependencies": {
        "angular": "1.4.8",
        "angular-aria": "1.4.8",
        "angular-bootstrap": "0.14.3",
        "angular-cache-buster": "0.4.3",
        "angular-cookies": "1.4.8",
        "angular-dynamic-locale": "0.1.28",
        "angular-i18n": "1.4.8",
        "angular-local-storage": "0.2.3",
        "angular-loading-bar": "0.8.0",
        "angular-resource": "1.4.8",
        "angular-sanitize": "1.4.8",
        "angular-translate": "2.8.1",
        "angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat": "2.8.1",
        "angular-translate-loader-partial": "2.8.1",
        "angular-translate-storage-cookie": "2.8.1",
        "angular-ui-router": "0.2.15",
        "bootstrap": "3.3.5",
        "jquery": "2.1.4",
        "json3": "3.3.2",
        "modernizr": "3.2.0",
        "ng-file-upload": "10.0.2",
        "ngInfiniteScroll": "1.2.1",
        "swagger-ui": "2.1.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "angular-mocks": "1.4.8",
        "angular-scenario": "1.4.8"
    },
    "overrides": {
        "bootstrap": {
            "main": [
                "dist/js/bootstrap.js",
                "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
                "less/bootstrap.less"
            ]
        }
    },
    "resolutions": {
        "angular": "1.4.8",
        "angular-cookies": "1.4.8",
        "jquery": "2.1.4"
    }
}
```

how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You had an error (probably a network issue) when generating your application.

As written in the last message when you generate an application, please run `npm install` and `bower install` again.